# Запретить изменение HTML структуры CKEditor

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg

Зачастую редакторы статей могут испортить структуру статьи: убрать заголовок, или изменить жирность шрифта и так далее. Появилось желание отгородить простых редакторов от HTML вообще, чтобы они изменяли только текст внутри тэгов, а все тэги оставались на своем месте. Возможно ли такое реализовать? Может есть какой-то другой редактор по мимо ckeditor, который даёт подобные возможности?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, у ckeditor можно настроить панели инструментов и кнопки, которые будут отображаться. Где-то это прописывается в файле конфигурации, там можно убрать кнопку отвечающую за включение режима редактирования html

Comment: Да, но они и без этого могут например добавить лишний абзац, или же убрать заголовок.

Comment: Получается, чтобы добиться изменения только самого текста необходимо разбить текст на маленькие текстовые поля исключительно с текстом?